# Combine Tensorflow v1 with raw python code

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to build a complex tensorflow graph and now I'm running into the problem of needing lists or for-loops at some point in the graph. Therefore now simplified my question with this code:

This is my "graph":

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(4, 1))
list = []
for i in range(int(x.shape[0])):
    print("hello")
    list.append(x[i])

r = tf.convert_to_tensor(list)
```

Then i call:

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  input = np.random.rand(4, 1)
  print(input)
  print(sess.run(r, feed_dict={x: input}))
  print(sess.run(r, feed_dict={x: input}))
```

Result is as expected:

```
Org: [[0.02942727]
 [0.22208347]
 [0.71572471]
 [0.13329401]]
First eval: [[0.02942727]
 [0.22208346]
 [0.7157247 ]
 [0.13329402]]
First eval: [[0.02942727]
 [0.22208346]
 [0.7157247 ]
 [0.13329402]]
```

It seems like the code works correctly, but I don't understand how this works. Normally, I would define some tf operations and it would be called only one time. Then, I can evaluate a node in the tensorflow graph.

How can this be applied to my example here? When I call `sess.run(r)`, how is this node inferred from the graph? It depends on the `for-loop` and `list` is just a raw python object and not a tensor at all?

What is the usual way if you can't avoid combining tensorflow with for-loops / dynamic lists?

Answer (score 0):

1. When I call sess.run(r), how is this node inferred from the graph?

your entire graph is basically one operation. It is the r operation, which is the function tf.convert_to_tensor

2. it depends on the for-loop and list

No, it does not. when you do
tf.convert_to_tensor(list)
you are basically adding to your graph
tf.convert_to_tensor([x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3] ])
Your entire graph is still just one function which depends on the x placeholder

Then, finally, when you run the operation in a session, you are providing the x placeholder which has the expected shape (4)